# fetching data from mongodb and electron js using ipc renderer

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, electron

> vue file

```
this.$electron.ipcRenderer.send('get-result')
      this.$electron.ipcRenderer.on('got-it', (event, data) => {
        if (data.status) {
          this.allResult = data.result
        }
        else{
          this.allResult = ''
        }
      })
```

> renderer file

```
ipcMain.on('get-result', (event) => {
    todolist.find({}, null, {sort: { creationDate: -1 }}, (err, result) => {
        if (!err && result.length) {
            event.sender.send('got-it', {
                status: true,
                result: result
            });
        } else {
            event.sender.send('got-it', {
                status: false
            });
        }
    });
});
```

IN CMD results look like this which is OK

```
[ { _id: 5dd01fff35ad336558153f8c,
      notes: 'hello 3',
      creationDate: 2019-11-16T16:12:47.190Z,
      __v: 0 },
    { _id: 5dd01efdca8cdf61daa07fcf,
      notes: 'Hello Again',
      creationDate: 2019-11-16T16:08:29.190Z,
      __v: 0 },
    { _id: 5dd01d7a2a4b995f68d36f7c,
      notes: 'Hello Mongo Atlas',
      creationDate: 2019-11-16T16:02:02.998Z,
      __v: 0 },
    { _id: 5dd01c72d43db25eb93c0267,
      notes: 'hello mongo',
      creationDate: 2019-11-16T15:57:38.799Z,
      __v: 0 } ]
```

But after getting result from renderer browser console look like this

```
0:$__:(...)
$init:(...)
$locals:(...)
isNew:(...)
_doc:(...)
__ob__
:Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get $__:ƒ reactiveGetter()
set $__:ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get $init:ƒ reactiveGetter()
set $init:ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get $locals:ƒ reactiveGetter()
set $locals:ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
```

and final results are in under the **_doc** of every index like 0, 1, 2
why is that ? I think it supposed to return just simple array like **CMD's** printed result.
Is that anything left to fetching organize result or i need to do something else ?

Thank you

Comment: is `allResult` declared on your Vue instance?

Comment: ya. allResult is declared in data() which is basically a array()

Comment: By the way, this problem is not arise for this.allResult. cz, after getting result from renderer file it shows the above result on browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Best way ignore this type of format is, after getting result from DB encode in json and then of font-end decode json format which will generate desire result. Like this-

> render.js

```
ipcMain.on('get-result', (event) => {
    todolist.aggregate([
        {
            $sort:{
                _id:-1
            }
        }
    ])
    .exec((err, result) => {
        if (!err && result.length) {
            event.sender.send('got-it', {
                status: true,
                result: JSON.stringify(result)
            });
        } else {
            event.sender.send('got-it', {
                status: false
            });
        }
    });
});
```

> component.vue

```
this.$electron.ipcRenderer.send('get-result')
      this.$electron.ipcRenderer.on('got-it', (event, data) => {
        if (data.status) {
          this.allResult = JSON.parse(data.result)
        }
        else{
          this.allResult = ''
        }
      })
```